# Save new image src in style via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I am trying to do a header image changer like when you click an image to change the style of the header and save it after reload. For example: I have the default image using a style in the header  and when I press the button to change it to automatically save it, even at refresh.

```js
function changetoimg1() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.background = "url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg)";
}

function changetoimg2() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.background = "url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg)";
}

function changetoimg3() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.background = "url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg)";
}
```

```css
.test{
    background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg');
    border: 0;
    padding: 37px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 70px;
}

.test2{
    background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg');
    border: 0;
   padding: 37px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 70px;
}

.test3{
    background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg');
    border: 0;
    padding: 37px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 70px;
}

.imageshdr{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -245px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 191%;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/oKe8JBR.png');">
<div class="imageshdr"><button onclick="changetoimg1()" class="test"></button>
<button onclick="changetoimg2()" class="test2"></button>
<button onclick="changetoimg3()" class="test3"></button></div>
```

Comment: store an id in window.sessionStorage and serve the src indexed by this value.

Comment: If you can be more specified please.. I am a newbie in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to repeat the code and you didn't give properties to `#header`

This answer is based on my understanding of your question.

```js
window.onload=()=>{
  let image=localStorage.getItem("dataImage");
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage=`url('${image}')`;
}
function changetoimg() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg')";
  localStorage.setItem("dataImage","https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg")
}
```

```css
#header{
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/oKe8JBR.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat ;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;

}
.test{
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg');
  border: 0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  padding: 37px;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-left: 70px;
  color:red
}

.imageshdr{
  position: absolute;
  /* margin-top: -245px; */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  height:300px;
  /* margin-left: 191%; */
}
```

```html
<header id="header"></header>
    <div class="imageshdr">
        <button onclick="changetoimg()" class="test">test</button>
        <button onclick="changetoimg()" class="test">test2</button>
        <button onclick="changetoimg()" class="test">test3</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's exactly the code for it, I just want to do so: when I change the header into the first image for example, this image to be saved on reload.

Comment: My code goes like that when I change the image and I refresh the page:

background-image: url((unknown));

Comment: you can try this `window.onload=()=>{
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("dataImage")){
    let image=sessionStorage.getItem("dataImage");
    document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage=`url('${image}')`;
  }
}`

Comment: images dissapear

Comment: also, wnhe I tried to put it like so: document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage= `url('${image}')`; the whole "`url('${image}')`" turns to red

Answer (score 0):

Use event listeners is a better practice.
Use sessionStorage to keep current status on reload; you can use localStorage if you want this to be kept when browser is closed.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
// charge the image on load
changeimage(false);
// add the click action on each button
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.imageshdr button');
[].forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    changeimage(true);
    });
  });
});

function changeimage(next) {
var i = 0;
// retrieve the current index if stored
if(sessionStorage.getItem('myheader') != null) i = sessionStorage.getItem('myheader');
// go on next if requested
if(next) i+=1;
// max i = 3
i=i%3;
sessionStorage.setItem('myheader',i);
alert("set image " + i);
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
<div class="imageshdr">
<button class="test"></button>
<button class="test2"></button>
<button class="test3"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Which part ? Do you understand the logic at least ?

Comment: not really, I tried the code and changed some elements but my img doesn't change when I click a button.

Comment: I edited and you should have your button alerting " set image ". Change this line by the header background switch like header.style.background... = image[i]

Answer (score 0):

You can save background image url in local storage when you click on button like below.

```
  function changetoimg1() {
    localStorage.setItem("background-image", "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg");
  document.getElementById("header").style.background = "url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg)";
}
```

And on document load you can set background image URL from local storage if it present like below,

```
let imgurl=localStorage.getItem("background-image")
    if(imgurl)
   document.getElementById("header").style.background = `url(${imgurl})`;
```